# How to make a 3-port component using pst-optexp

Tags: pstricks, pst-optexp

I'm wanting to create a custom component using the `pst-optexp` package. So far, I've figured out how to make a two-port custom component that shows the internal structure, but I can't figure out how to make a three-port custom component that shows the internal structure.

Perhaps the solution is to do something like `makeatletter` and `makeatother`. I was able to use this to get the square wave for the function generator, but I don't have enough LaTeX mana to cast that sort of wizardry on the \optdipolecomp.

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-optexp}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}


\makeatletter
    \def\elecsynthesizer@custom{%
    \psline(-0.25,0)(-0.25,0.15)(0,.15)%
    (0,-.15)(0.25,-.15)(.25,0)}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-2, 2)(12,-12)

    \def\loopRadius{1}
    \def\loopAngleOne{135}
    \def\loopAngleTwo{45}

    \pnode(5.5,-6){loopCenter}
    \pnode([nodesep=\loopRadius,angle=135]loopCenter){loopTop}
    \pnode([nodesep=\loopRadius,angle=-135]loopCenter){loopBottom}

    \addtopsstyle{Fiber}{linecolor=red}
    \psset{fiber=none}
    \newpsstyle{OptCircArrow}{arrows=<-,unit=.6}



    \def\phasemodulatorcomp{%

        \psframe(-.7,-0.4)(.7,0.4)
        \psline(-.7,0)(-.2,0)(.1,.3)(.7,.3)
        \psline(-.2,0)(.1,-.3)(.7,-.3)}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DOES NOT SHOW THE INTERNAL STRUCTURE, BUT HAS TWO PORTS 
    \newpsobject{mioc}{fiberbox}{fiberboxcount=1x2,fiberboxsize=1.5 0.8, extnode=b,showifcnodes }


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% SHOWS THE INTERNAL STRUCTURE, BUT ONLY HAS ONE PORT ON EACH SIDE
    %\newpsobject{mioc}{optdipole}{optdipolesize=1.5 0.8,optdipolecomp={\phasemodulatorcomp}, extnode=b,showifcnodes }

    \pnodes(3,0){A}(6,0){B}


    \pnode(0,0){A}
    \pnode([nodesep=5,angle=-90]A){B}
    \pnode([nodesep=1,angle=-90]B){circ}
    \pnode([nodesep=2,angle=0]circ){miocLoc}
    \pnode([nodesep=3,angle=-90]circ){detectorLoc}

    \optbox     [position=start,compname=laser,labelref=relative,labeloffset=0](A)(B){laser}
    \optisolator[position=.4,compname=isolator](A)(B)
    \optbox     [position=.8,extnode=b,compname=EOM,labelref=relative,labeloffset=0](A)(B){EOM}

    \pnode(\oenodeExt{EOM}){pmr}

    \pnode([nodesep=10,angle=0]pmr){E}

    \optbox[compname=noiseGen,position=start,labeloffset=0,labelref=relative](E)(pmr){noise}
    \optamp[position=.1,compname=preamp1](E)(pmr){+12 dB}
    \optamp[position=.3,compname=preamp2](E)(pmr){+12 dB}
    \optbox[position=.5,compname=attenuators](E)(pmr){-7 dB}
    \optamp[position=.7,compname=preamp3](E)(pmr){+12 dB}
    \optamp[position=.9,compname=amp](E)(pmr){+14 dB}

    \drawwire{noiseGen}{preamp1}{preamp2}{attenuators}{preamp3}{amp}(pmr)

    \optcirculator[optcircangle=180 0,compname=circulator](detectorLoc)(B)(miocLoc)

    \drawfiber{laser}{isolator}{EOM}{circulator}



    \mioc[position=end,compname=mioc,labeloffset=0](circ)(miocLoc){MIOC}
    \drawfiber[startnode=2,fiberangleA=-90]{circulator}{mioc}


    \drawfiber[startnode=2,fiberangleB=\loopAngleTwo]{mioc}(loopTop)
    \drawfiber[startnode=3,fiberangleB=-\loopAngleTwo]{mioc}(loopBottom)
    \psarc[linecolor=red]{-}(loopCenter){\loopRadius}{-\loopAngleOne}{\loopAngleOne}




    \optdetector[compname=detector,dettype=diode,extnode=b](circ)(detectorLoc)

    \pnode(\oenodeExt{detector}){detectorExit}
    \pnode([nodesep=4,angle=0]detectorExit){liaLoc}
    \optbox[position=end,compname=lia,extnode=t,labeloffset=0](detectorExit)(\oenodeExt{mioc}|liaLoc){LIA}

    \elecsynthesizer[position=.5,synthtype=custom](\oenodeExt{mioc})(\oenodeExt{lia})

    \drawwire(detectorExit){lia}
    \drawfiber{circulator}{detector}
    \pnode([nodesep=2,angle=0]liaLoc){output}
    \cnodeput([nodesep=1,angle=0]output){output2}{output}
    \drawwire[arrows=->]{lia}(output)

    \end{pspicture}
%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to draw a `fiberbox` with custom internal structure you must define your own macro to call `\fiberbox` with changed `\fiberbox@comp`. 
The internal macro `fiberbox@comp` simply draws the fiberbox rectangle. Here, you already have access to the fiberbox's input and output nodes which you use with `\oenode{1}{}`:

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-optexp}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\makeatletter
\def\phasemodulatorcomp{%
  \pcdiag[angleB=180, arm=0.6](\oenode{1}{})(\oenode{2}{})
  \pcdiag[angleB=180, arm=0.6](\oenode{1}{})(\oenode{N}{})}

\def\mioc{%
   \let\fiberbox@comp@orig\fiberbox@comp
   \def\fiberbox@comp{\fiberbox@comp@orig\phasemodulatorcomp}
   \fiberbox}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(6,2)
  \addtopsstyle{Fiber}{linecolor=red}
  \pnode(0,1){In}
  \pnode(2,1){Out}
  \mioc[fiberboxcount=1x2, fiberboxsize=1.5 0.8, extnode=b,showifcnodes, position=end,compname=mioc](In)(Out){MIOC}
  \drawfiber{}([Xnodesep=1, offset=0.4]\oenode{2}{})
  \drawfiber{}([Xnodesep=1, offset=-0.4]\oenode{3}{})
  \pccurve[style=Fiber, ncurv=1.2]([Xnodesep=1, offset=0.4]\oenode{2}{})([Xnodesep=1, offset=-0.4]\oenode{3}{})
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

That makes me think of adding a parameter `fiberboxcomp` or similar which would allow you to define the "derived" fiberbox with it's internal structure with `\newpsobject`. Maybe it would be worth doing this also for the elecsynthesizer.